# make php page cannot access when the user want try

Tags: php

How make my php page cannot access by the user, i mean when the try type some php page, they cannot access it, with some text "sory un authorized page" or just redirect it to another page that related with the php page too,

like this:
    **www.mydomain.com/index.php become www.mydomain.com/home or /home.html**
    **www.mydomain.com/profile.php becomee www.mydomain.com/profiles**
so the user only type the rewrite page not the php page.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just keep that particular script outside of the document root? Remove access completely instead.

Comment: To achieve the second part of your question, do a [web search for 'routing'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=htaccess+routing+php).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$isAllowed)
{
    (Redirect them)
}
```

Very simple.

http://www.instant-web-site-tools.com/html-redirect.html

And

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Both show methods of redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`header` for redirect and `exit` or `die` to stop page execution

```
$url = "http://www.mydomain.com/home";
$isValidUser = false ;

if(!$isValidUser)
{
    header("Localtion: $url");
}
```

Or

```
$isValidUser = false ;
if(!$isValidUser)
{
    die("Sorry un authorized page");
}
```

Please See

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php